# Парсинг стены сообщества в ВК

Tags: python, парсер, vkontakte-api

Доброго времени суток!

Написал парсер стены в Вк, все работает, как надо, за исключением получения просмотров видео, если в публикации прикреплено видео. Завернул получение этого параметра в `if: else:`, как в туториале, который смотрел. А так же в `try: except:`

```
for post in all_posts:
   try:
      if post ['attachments'][0]['type']==['video']:
         video_views = ['attachments'][0]['video']['views']
      else:
         video_views = '0'
   except:
      pass
a_pen.writerow((f"https://vk.com/er_saint_p?w=wall-82258040_{post ['id']}", post['likes']['count'], post ['comments']['count'], post['reposts']['count'], video_views, post['views']['count']))
```

Получается так, что если не использовать `try: except:` код выдает ошибку, а при использовании, пропускает каждый пост через `except:`. Я знаю, что у меня в списке есть посты с видео, но "просмотры видео" в каждой строке итоговой таблицы по 0.

Как поправить эту часть?

Comment: я подозреваю, что в исходном словаре, к ключам которого вы обращаетесь, значение ключа `'type'` является просто строка `'video'`, а не список `['video']`. И использовать `try/except` без указания конкретной ошибки не лучшая практика, как и пользоваться обращением по ключу напрямую, а не через метод `.get()`  .

Comment: Я тут в [tag:парсер] ранее уже отвечал про просмотры, всё парсится отлично. Какая именно страница и что необходимо получить?

Comment: Добрый вечер! Страница сообщества, необходимо получить просмотры видео (не самой записи с видео = охват публикации), если во вложении есть видео. То есть если пост с фото, то в итоговой таблице с результатами в поле "просмотры видео" ставится "0", если пост с видео, в том же поле ставится соответствующее число.

Comment: @NikitaVshivkov ну а пример, ссылку на сообщество, можно?

Comment: @DiMithras, https://vk.com/er_saint_p

Comment: @NikitaVshivkov посмотрю через пару дней.